# TFS - Create Task item without parent

Tags: tfs, tfs-2015

Is it possible to create new backlog item as a Task standalone without parent (not under user story or bugs). Sometime only single task is small to be a user story.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not exactly on the backlog. It's not designed to support orphaned tasks. However, you can easily create a task without a parent in the Queries interface. Just go to Work -> Queries, click New -> Task (upper left), and there you have a task. You can then view it in the sprint iteration beneath "Unparented". You can also view them in Queries, of course. You won't be able to see them in the product backlog, though, since it only shows parented items.